# How to write a function that passes different key word arguments to different functions

Tags: function, python-3.x, keyword-argument

I would like to write a function that passes different keyword arguments to different functions.

For example, I want to write a function that plots a histogram of my data by first creating axes via `gca` and then adding the histogram via `hist`. I would like the user to be able to pass additional keyword arguments to both `gca` and `hist`.

Something like this (syntax error in the defintion line) is what I'm looking for,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

def plot_hist(data, **kwargs_hist, **kwargs_gca):
    ax = plt.gca(**kwargs_gca)       
    fig = ax.hist(data, **kwargs_hist)[0]
    return fig
```

Comment: how would python know which keywords to pass to each function?  Especially considering that `inspect.signature(plt.gca) -> <Signature (**kwargs)>`

Comment: What is it that defines where the keyword argument goes?

Comment: @tadhg That's exactly the problem I'm trying to solve. Am I able to accomplish something like this?

Comment: @zondo I would like the user to decide which optional arguments to pass to `hist` and which to `gca`

Comment: well you could just have the user pass two dictionaries instead of keywords, then you would call it like `plot_hist(DATA, dict(var1=1, var2=2), dict(var3=3, var4=4))` and just remove the `**` in the definition line.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen Thanks! Write it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing exactly which keyword arguments to delegate to each function the `**keywords` just isn't going to work in this scenario, you can instead take two dictionaries for the keywords to each function as arguments:

```
def plot_hist(data, kwargs_hist={}, kwargs_gca={}):
    ax = plt.gca(**kwargs_gca)       
    fig = ax.hist(data, **kwargs_hist)[0]
    return fig
```

and then make the separate dictionaries, the keyword syntax can still be used by passing them to the `dict` constructor:

```
plot_hist(DATA, dict(hist_arg=3, foo=6), dict(gca_arg=1, bar = 4))
```